# best way to use magento 2.4 on windows 10 for development

Tags: development, magento2.4, pagespeed

I am using magento 2.4 on wamp in windows 10 with 500GB hard disk core i5 processor and 12GB RAM.
I am developing a functionalities in magento 2.4 instance but problem is magento 2.4 is slow without cache. When I do some changes in store configuration or in phtml,block file I have to disable full page cache or clear full page cache to reflect my changes on website.

If I do changes and clear full page cache and refresh the page ,it takes time to load the page and that's why my developing is slow. My friend runs magento 2.4 on linux with low hardware configuration .In my friend's pc magento 2.4 is working fast even he disabled full page cache to developing a new functionality.

**What should I do to run smoothly and fast developing in magento 2.4 in windows 10 without switching on linux OS ?**

Comment: how much time it takes to load page ?

Comment: @hamendrasunthwal it takes 40 sec to load page after clear cache in fresh instance

Comment: @hamendrasunthwal same time take in magento 2.3.4 version also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From version 2.4 onwards, Magento won't suggest to run it on Windows and Mac operating system specially for development purpose.

**Devdocs Reference :**

[image]

Many things will not work properly like GraphQL, sometimes you also need to delete generated folder to load frontend. These are the things which I already experienced while running Magento 2.4 on windows. I would suggest you to switch onto linux OS to make it work smoother.

Comment: Thanks bro. Appreciate